# Does BindingExpression (path) error affect the performance?

Tags: wpf, binding

We have some derived control classes which have specific data. And these controls also set the data error info and binding to some specific property. For example, if the property IsNew (providing it exists) is true then the background is highlighted.

Now I want to know, what if I use these controls and bind to some objects which do not expose such property as IsNew? Will it affect the performance for Release version?

Comment: No it won't affect performance, however it seems that you entire approach is backwards. Post the relevant code and XAML.

Comment: @HighCore I realized that this design is not perfect. But the reason we have such customized controls is, for example, we have some common frequently-used items for combo box, and also for some styling reason. Frankly I had some hesitation about such design too, because it seems to tightly couple the Controls and the Model/ViewModel. But that's our current design and I admit it somehow makes it a bit easier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error in itself will not cause any additional performance issues, but the constant `Binding` checks will and do cause some very minor (practically unnoticeable) performance issues. This is one of the many reasons why WPF performs less well than many other languages. However, these checks will go on whether you have errors or not.

The only time that having errors will actually slow down your program is when your are using the [`PresentationTraceSources` to output information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409960.aspx) into the Output Window of Visual Studio or worse still, into an external trace file. However, even in these cases, it is unlikely that you will find a noticeable drop in performance, unless you have set the WPF Trace Settings to the most verbose setting of `Verbose`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. In release version we don't have any such tracing utility, so it should be OK. And this binding performance is always a puzzle to me since it is hard to debug (since debug uses different setting than release)