# Will BindingError's slow's down Application Performance?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, binding

I have developed WPF application. In which I added lots of heavy Control's. But now I'm trying to improve my application's performance. I analysed a bit & found that there are lot of `Binding Data Error's` running in `Output Window`.

So, Will these error's impacts on Application's Performance as much?

Comment: Binding errors are only printed out at debug time in output window. I checked it out a while ago. Here is the official source code. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ there you will be able to find the binding engine code

Comment: "WPF tries several different ways to resolve path errors, including searching for attached properties and this is quite expensive" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/02/wpf-in-visual-studio-2010-part-2-performance-tuning.aspx

Comment: Yes they will. Binding mechanism consumes exceptions(property not found or exceptions during setting/getting value)

Comment: I gave you link to source code. Find the piece you think that damages performance and then we can talk about it

Comment: You definitely should try to fix binding errors unless they are known issues and can't be fixed or workaround is too *expensive* (time-wise, performance-wise, etc.). But I don't understand what means *heavy Control's*. In what way heavy? If you use a lot of shadows, transparency and animations, then your application simply require better hardware or you can make UI less shiny. If you have heavy processing, than it's a whole another story, mostly to utilize more CPU and use more effective ways to process data.

Comment: The errors will *not* affect performance, however the Presentation Trace Sources that display them in the Visual Studio Output window can. Therefore, they will *not* affect performance in a Release version application.

Comment: If performance is not affecting, then it is not necessory to fix those error's??.. Am I right???

Comment: But I found lots of articles on net for performance improvements, & they are saying it should be necessory to fix binding errors in order to improve applications performance...

Comment: Obviously you don't need these bindings that are failing - otherwise you would have realized during testing that something wasn't working properly. With that, it is also obvious that the application would be faster if you didn't have these failing bindings - there wouldn't need to be any (failed) effort by the run-time to resolve them. Whether the speedup that could be gained by eliminating them is significant is a different matter, of course.

Comment: I need canonical answer in `Answers Section`, not in comments.. Everyone just commenting.. Please answer this thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As there is a bounty on this question I am unable to mark it as a duplicate of this question: [Does BindingExpression (path) error affect the performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541265/does-bindingexpression-path-error-affect-the-performance)

For the ease of anyone navigating to this question in search of an answer:

- The Binding Data Error itself does not cause any performance issues.
- The trace output will, but that won't affect Release build.
- The binding framework trying and failing every possible binding method for this property will marginally impact performance.

The last point is the most significant.  It is best to tidy up your binding so that work you know will fail isn't being performed unnecessarily every time you bind.  If you don't resolve these errors and let them accumulate as you add more data bound controls, the performance of your application's binding will degrade accordingly.